# Are there any coding standards for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

What are the established coding standards for JavaScript?

Comment: Seeing this question still shows up in google search I thought adding this might be relevant. JavaScript is an implementation of ECMAScript script, following the ECMA standards. [**Standard ECMA-262**](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). To add from the [**ECMA wiki page**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript): `Netscape delivered JavaScript to Ecma International for standardization and the work on the specification, ECMA-262, began in November 1996`

Comment: Closed AND protected. Huh!?!

Comment: http://www.sourceformat.com/pdf/javascript-coding-standard-apple.pdf

Comment: http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: // , WHHHHYYYY was this closed? It's an excellent question for new Javascript programmers. Especially given the, ah, state of most original Javascript code written by new programmers.

Comment: This is VERY constructive, and an excellent fit for the SE Q&A format.

Comment: The random closing hammer strikes again!

Comment: You can use Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide for up to date coding standards https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but (like Doug Crockford's vids) I think everybody who writes/edits/reviews JS should look at Chris Heilmann's [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/cheilmann/fronteers-maintainability-presentation) and [videos](http://ajaxian.com/archives/maintainable-javascript-videos-are-now-available) on maintainable javascript.

In the [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/cheilmann/fronteers-maintainability-presentation), slide 127, he says don't worry so much about style guides/code standards, reformat all code checked in to VCS.

Also these:

[Mozilla JavaScript Tips](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_style_guide)

[JavaScript Style Guide](http://neil.rashbrook.org/Js.htm)

Comment: Google also has a style guide: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml

Comment: In an attempt to solve this question (finding and deciding on a JavaScript Code Style, while allowing for some flexibility), I've created http://jscode.org where you can generate custom code styles according to some settings (yeah, it may sound like blatant advertising, but I'm not gaining anything there, I just built this for myself and my team, and I think it's of good value).

Comment: The Mozilla JavaScript Tips is very sparse, I wouldn't include it.

Comment: All the links broken. this is an example of a BAD Answer

Answer (score 24):

Another reason why [Crockford's JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) coding guidelines are a good idea to follow:

This code (below) actually returns undefined because of JavaScript's semicolon injection - which is a damn good reason to get the whole team of developers singing from the same song sheet:

```
return // injected semicolon, therefore returns 'undefined'
{
    javascript : "fantastic"
}; // object constructs anonymously but nothing happens with it.
```

Bit more about that at [Beware of JavaScript semicolon insertion](http://www.robertnyman.com/2008/10/16/beware-of-javascript-semicolon-insertion)

Comment: There is also JSLint to help automate/verify some of these guidelines. http://www.jslint.com/

Answer (score 10):

I never saw a widely acknowledged JavaScript coding standard out there. We did write our own some time ago and I [published it on my blog](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2007/02/05/105493.aspx) in accordance with my employer.

Keep in mind that some of the guidelines might be a bit outdated.

Comment: This document has reference to 'C# programming guidelines'. Do you have it publicly available as well?

Answer (score 8):

Google has posted a [Javascript guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)

Comment: This is a "link only" answer and the link does not work anymore which is exactly why "link only answers" should be avoided.

Answer (score 6):

You can find some simple but essential coding conventions at the [Google Code Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library-dev/wiki/JavascriptCodingConventions).

For very detailed style guides read the [Dojo Style Guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/community/styleGuide). It is going over naming conventions, file conventions, variable usage, code layout, whitespace, and comments.

Answer (score 4):

A bit puzzled that I cannot find on the replies 
[Idiomatic.js](https://github.com/rwldrn/idiomatic.js) and 
[jQuery Core Style Guide](http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_Core_Style_Guidelines). Addy Osmani puts those two on the very top of full list of coding styles for JavaScript in his "JavaScript Style Guides And Beautifiers" article.

I personally prefer jQuery standard, though it doesn't much differ from Idiomatic.js. But whatever standard you choose you will need a validator to check how successful you are following it. I couldn't find any for jQuery or at least Idiomatic, but eventually came up with [JS_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/dsheiko/jscodesniffer)

Answer (score 3):

The [comp.lang.javascript Code Guidelines](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/code-guidelines/) document points to causes of errors and problems related to javascript for web applications and how to avoid them.

Answer (score 2):

Myself and a few others recently put together [these](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_contribute_codingStandards.ashx) (PDF or HTML)

They are primarily intended for use with the Ajax Control Toolkit but realistically contain all sorts of useful guidance whichever framework you use.

Hope that helps.