# OOP In javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

Im wondering which way of using OOP in Javascript ist best way to go with.

There is this prototype thing and you have the function style way. But both have very bad ways to inherit a base class.

So I tried to build a way to make this possible without having to use prototype and such.

```
function Car(name) {
    this.Name = name;

    this.FullName = function () {
        return this.Name;
    }
}

function SpecialCar(name, variant) {
    //BaseClass.apply(this, PARAMS AS ARRAY);
    Car.apply( this, [name] );

    //new property
    this.Variant = variant;

    //override function
    this.FullName = function () {
        return this.Name + " " + this.Variant ;
    }
}

var audi = new Car("audi");
$("#result").append(audi.FullName() + "<br>");

var audia3 = new SpecialCar("audi", "a3");
$("#result").append(audia3.FullName()+ "<br>");
```

You can check the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vu9ZF/2/

Is this okay or is it just bad-practice?

Would be very nice to get some answers why other ways are better because I just dont get it.

**EDIT: Thank you all for answering me so fast! 
I was trying to find some way of OOP in javascript for myself, not answering on how to do oop in javascript.
I dont like the way of using prototype for that because im using c# most of my worktime and its a bit confusing to switch between "c#-like oop" and "prototype oop".
But someone in the comments told me that avoiding prototype isnt a good idea, soo ill drop that.**

Thanks stackoverflow your all awesome & saved me so much time =)

Comment: I'd checkout Mootools if I were you. It has a Class system built into into thats very easy to understand.

Comment: :/ I cant use other frameworks than kendoui and jquery in my project

Comment: @ChaosPandion Because its completely different than in other languages.

Comment: If you look at the Related pane to the bottom right, you'll find some good answers/direction to this question.

Comment: @SSchnitzler - Think about it for a second... does that reason make much sense logically?

Comment: @SSchnitzler that's because it _is_ a different language. It is **not** C(++|#) or Java and will require learning new ways of doing things to use correctly.

Comment: Downvote for saying that a prototype/functional language can't inherit from a CLASS very well...

Comment: Yeah it is a different language, but thats why im looking for a way to do it the way i do it the rest of my day in other languages. (like my sample above)

And i did not say that its not done very well with prototype. But compared with the way other languages do it, prototype still is a bit strange for me.

Comment: @SSchnitzler's point stands, though. People dislike using prototypes *because it's different*. In most OOP courses, you're taught classical OO. Since prototypal is different, most people will be resistant to it, and will find the constructor pattern to be easier to understand.

Comment: @Ryan Kinal - I suppose you're right. Human nature is in play here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how it's done:

```
function Car ( name ) {
    this.name = name;
}

Car.prototype.fullName = function () {
    return this.name;
}

function SpecialCar ( name, variant ) {
    Car.apply( this, arguments );
    this.variant = variant;
}

SpecialCar.prototype = Object.create( Car.prototype );

SpecialCar.prototype.fullName = function () {
    return this.name + ' ' + this.variant;
};
```

(You need to shim `Object.create` for IE8)

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3Rehr/

---

So, the methods should be assigned to the constructor's prototype object, *not* to the instances themselves.

Also, in order to pre-process the instance with the super-constructor, simply do this:

```
Car.apply( this, arguments );
```

so the `this.base` thing is not needed.

Comment: I know how to do classes and how to inherit them. Its just that i want to know why its done this way and if my way is bad practice. But anyway thanks for your answer. My way shown above works too.

Comment: I believe he wants to know why other ways are better?

Comment: @SSchnitzler The code shown in your question is not optimal. You're assigning the methods directly to the instances. You want to assign the methods to the constructor's prototypes instead. Also, the `this.base` is also not optimal. You can work with the `this` value directly.

Comment: @SSchnitzler Ah, I see, you explicitly tried to avoid the prototype objects. Well, that is definitely not a good idea. The methods *should* be inherited from the prototype. That way, there exists only one instance of each method which is inherited by all instances.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Thanks, thats the answer i was looking for. Then I'll drop my idea.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Can you please update the answer with what you have mentioned in the comments?

Comment: Thank you very very much. Can you please check my question-edit and see if its okay now?

Comment: @SSchnitzler You mean your updated demo? Well, you still haven't relocated the methods to the prototypes...

Comment: Do I have to do that with the script in this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/vu9ZF/3/ Keep in mind that there will not be anything in the prototypes from the base class because I am trying not to use them

Comment: @SSchnitzler I don't understand. You still don't want to use the prototype objects?

Comment: @SSchnitzler Just look at my answer. The `Car.prototype.fullName` has to be *outside* of the constructor's body. Also, you need to manually set up the inheritance (`B.prototype = Object.create( A.prototype );`. It's all in my answer.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Okay I was confused about the whole prototype thing, i now know the advantage of using it.

Comment: @SSchnitzler It takes some time to figure out the correct patterns, but once you understand them (and got used to them), you're fine `:)`

Comment: What's the difference between `SpecialCar.prototype = Object.create( Car.prototype );` and how @davide did it: `SpecialCar.prototype = new Car(); SpecialCar.constructor = SpecialCar;`, is there no shim required for IE8?

Answer (score 3):

It's not particularly recommandable because you actually return a `Car` instance and not a `SpecialCar` instance.

```
audia3 instanceof Car === true;
audia3 instanceof SpecialCar === false;
```

This is confusing because you *do* execute `new SpecialCar`. Also properties of `SpecialCar.prototype` wouldn't be available on the instance, but you seem to be using a custom inheritance copying pattern.

Comment: Ooh, good point. +1. I've abandoned all pretense of a reliable `instanceof`, but still, it's a good point.

Comment: `instanceof` is reliable, it's just the way he did inheritance is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The way I usually go is the one described [in this page](http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html)

It gives the code a more structured link, even thou I like the feature in your code of being able to call the parent's constructor.

```
function Car( name ) {
  this.Name = name;
}

Car.prototype.FullName = function FullName() {
  return this.Name;
}


function SpecialCar( name, variant ) {
  this.Name = name;
  this.Variant = variant;
}

SpecialCar.prototype = new Car();
SpecialCar.constructor = SpecialCar;

SpecialCar.prototype.FullName = function FullName() {
  return this.Name + " " + this.Variant; 
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between `SpecialCar.prototype = Object.create( Car.prototype );` and how you did it: `SpecialCar.prototype = new Car(); SpecialCar.constructor = SpecialCar;`, is there no shim required for IE8?

Comment: @Knownasilya Using `Object.create` is the proper way to set up inheritance. `new Car()` also works but it it flawed as it pollutes the object with unnecessary instance properties (`.Name` in this case). And yes, you'll need to polyfill `Object.create` for IE8 (use es5-shim).

Answer (score 2):

As far as the constructor pattern goes, I actually prefer your method, rather than using `apply` or anything similar. It might get a little confusing due to the necessity of `return`, but it doesn't feel quite as dirty as `apply` to me.

However, I prefer using prototypal inheritance a little more directly, with `Object.create`:

```
var Car = {
    fullName: function() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

var SpecialCar = Object.create(Car);
SpecialCar.fullName = function() {
    return this.name + ' ' + this.variant;
};

var audi = Object.create(Car);
audi.name = 'audi';

var audiA3 = Object.create(SpecialCar);
audiA3.name = 'audi';
audiA3.variant = 'A3';
```

Some browsers don't support `Object.create` natively, but it is shimmable.

Comment: Your code won't work - the second argument of `Object.create` has to be a hash of property descriptors. A simple hash of properties is not valid. So: `Object.create( Car, { fullName: { value: function () { ... }, enumerable: true });`

Comment: Although I wish that your method was valid. Property descriptors suck `:P`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it. Needs some sugar code for it to work. You can find [OoJs on github](https://github.com/najamelan/TidBits_Javascript_OoJs). OoJs covers most of the OOP features from C++, except for multiple inheritance and enforcing pure virtual functions...

```
;( function class_Car( namespace )
{
    'use strict';

    if( namespace.Car ) return    // protect against double inclusions

        namespace.Car = Car
    var Static        = TidBits.OoJs.setupClass( namespace, "Car" )


    // constructor
    //
    function Car( name )
    {
        this.Name = name               // data member, private by default

        return this.Public( FullName ) // method FullName will be public
    }


    function FullName()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }

})( window )




;( function class_SpecialCar( namespace )
{
    'use strict';

    if( namespace.SpecialCar ) return    // protect against double inclusions

        namespace.SpecialCar = SpecialCar
    var Static               = TidBits.OoJs.setupClass( namespace, "SpecialCar", "Car" )


    // constructor
    //
    function SpecialCar( name, variant )
    {
        this.Super( name )

        this.Variant = variant

        return this.Public( FullName )
    }


    function FullName()
    {
        return this.Car.FullName() + " " + this.Variant
    }

})( window )


var audi = new Car("audi");
$("#result").append(audi.FullName() + "<br>"); // output: audi

var audia3 = new SpecialCar("audi", "a3");
$("#result").append(audia3.FullName()+ "<br>"); // output: audi a3
```