# Javascript Module declaration - performance

Tags: javascript, performance

I am trying to decide between the following ways of writing JS module. What are the implications of writing a module on Memory and CPU. Will the 2nd one take up more Memory in the browser ?

Using function declaration

```
function MyModule () {
    this.getOperation1 =  operation1;
    function operation1() {
        return "XYZ"
    }
}
```

Using variable definition

```
 var MyModule = {
     getOperation1: function() {
        return "XYZ"
     }
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object Oriented Javascript best practices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907225/object-oriented-javascript-best-practices)

Comment: I reviewed the thread, it does not cover Memory / CPU angle of problem.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve at the end?

Comment: Trying to group functions in one module/namespace 1) to avoid name collision 2) Ease code maintenance

Comment: If the functions are being grouped just for name spacing purposes then use option #2 - see updated answer.  Only use #1 or the `.prototype` method if you're going to create multiple instances of the object (in the OOP sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory wise they're *about* the same - both create a single object.

However:

1. You can only use `new` with the function based module format.  The latter just creates a single object, not a constructor that can be used to create additional instances.
2. With a function you can enclose private local variables in the scope.

However, in *most* cases a better approach is this:

```
function MyModule () {
}

MyModule.prototype.getOperation1 = function() {
    ...
}
```

which ensures that if you create multiple instances they all only share *one* copy of the `getOperation1` function.

That said, if all you're trying to do is namespace the functions, and they don't naturally form an "object' (in the OOP sense) then you might just as well use the object literal syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this [yui-blog](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/13/javascript-we-hardly-new-ya/) for memory related argument

From the same

> By using new to invoke the function, the object holds onto a worthless
>   prototype object. That wastes memory with no offsetting advantage. If
>   we do not use the new, we don’t keep the wasted prototype object in
>   the chain

As mentioned by @Alnitak make use of `prototype` object incase you are up to implement `constructor` function so that all instances would share the same object.

To check CPU wise [speed] use www.jsperf.com and do a performance test. Some already available tests
[Function Invocation](http://jsperf.com/function-invocation-regular-call-apply-new/3),
[Object.create vs new](http://jsperf.com/object-create-vs-new-ctor/3), 
[Generic](http://jsperf.com/search?q=new)