# Is this Object Oriented Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is the following code equivalent to a class with associated functions? What is the difference between 'obj.start' function and startEngine() function? (Not logic wise, structural wise.. )

```
var Car = function (carElement)
{
            var obj = {},
                isRunning = false,
                dashboard,
                speed = 0,
                accelerometer,
                gearElement,
                transmission =
                {
                    'first': { ts: 15, rpm: 2 },
                    'second': { ts: 30, rpm: 4 },
                    'third': { ts: 50, rpm: 5 },
                    'fourth': { ts: 80, rpm: 5 },
                    'fifth': { ts: 110, rpm: 6 }
                };

        function startEngine()
        {
            //some code to start engine
        }

    obj.start = function ()
    { 
         //more code.. 
    }

    obj.stop = function ()
    {
        //even more code...
    };

   (function init()
   {
      obj.start();
   }());

return obj;
};
```

**[EDIT]** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907225/object-oriented-javascript-best-practices?rq=1) practically describes what my question is all about

Comment: see this answer about JS-Objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310353/how-to-read-json-result-in-jquery/23310376#23310376

Comment: @pc-shooter, thanks! However, does this really relate to how JS-Object can have properties and methods accessed with DOT notation? I see how `obj.start` is assigned a function and can be later accessed using obj.start(), however, it does not answer why one would use that instead of a function with a `normal` header `function startEngine()`.. and is Car considered to be a class here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the following code equivalent to a class with associated functions?

It depends on how you instantiate it. If you use the function declaration style (like startEngine uses), and if you instantiate it with the `new` keyword, and remove the `return` value then yes (though startEngine is private-like not public until you create a public pointer to it).

> What is the difference between 'obj.start' function and startEngine() function?

The differences are:

- startEngine is a function declaration, and so it is hoisted, unlike obj.start which is a anonymous function expression that isn't hoisted.
- startEngine is a private-like method of the `Car` "class". obj.start is not.
- obj.start is a method on the obj object, which is a property of the `Car` "class".
- obj is being returned if Car is called as a function (without the new keyword), therfore the methods of `obj` can be called from outside of `Car`, whereas startEngine isn't reachable from outside of `Car`, without a public pointer.