# JavaScript coding standards

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any coding standards for JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211795/are-there-any-coding-standards-for-javascript)

Is there any guidline describes what is standard notation for naming variables\functions etc?
What is best practice to write loops, conditionals, classes and other language constructions?

Answer (score 1):

You could start with [this](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html).

Answer (score 1):

This one has some good advice: [Front End Development Guidelines (HTML, CSS and JavaScript)](http://taitems.github.com/Front-End-Development-Guidelines/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this great site about [JavaScript Best Practices](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/) and the book [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596805531).

I also suggest you to follow [Douglas Crockford](http://www.crockford.com/) as is considered as one of the best JS experts out there.

When you feel you are an expert JavaScript programmer, it's time to read carefully the [ECMAScript Language Specifications](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).